# Get Full Path on HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to make a user-friendly Python program where the user enters the input in an **HTML** file instead of calling the functions from the console. One of the inputs is the directory of the dataset. because it is friendlier to show the user where he or she is choosing as the dataset path, I am using `<input type="file">`. however, I understand that for security reasons browsers won't return the full path of a folder but I was wondering if there is a way to get the full path when the server and the client are the same which is as friendly as `<input>` option.